# How do I remove "active" css class from breadcrumbs?

Tags: hooks, breadcrumbs, routes, rdf, theming

I am trying to include Structured Data in my breadcrumbs. The google validator throws an error on my final breadcrumb. When I remove class="active" from the code in the code validator window the code passes without error.

I used the theme_breadcrumb hook to add the Structured Data Markup to the breadcrumbs, but there is no mention of the css active class.

```
function MYTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
    $breadcrumb = substr_replace($breadcrumb, 'http://mywebsiteexample.com/', 9, 1); 
    $rich_snippet = 'rel="v:url" property="v:title" ';
    $breadcrumb = substr_replace($breadcrumb, $rich_snippet, 3, 0); 
    if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
        $breadcrumb[] = '<a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.current_path().'" >'.drupal_get_title().'</a>';
        //Added this line  to avoid displaying node title twice
        unset($breadcrumb[count($breadcrumb) - 1]);
        $output = '<span class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</span>'; 
        $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">' . implode(' » </span><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">', $breadcrumb) . '</span></div>'; 
        return $output; 
      }
    }
```

Is there another hook I can use to remove the active class exclusively for breadcrumbs? Ideally I would like to do it without inserting Javascript into any templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active class is added by the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
  // Append active class.
  if (($path == $_GET ['q'] || ($path == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) && 
    (empty($options ['language']) || $options ['language']->language == $language_url->language)) {
    $options ['attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }
```

It may be difficult to override this behavior. In your code replacing theme_breadcrumb it seems like you've hit upon this problem since you are not using the `l` function. You could loop over the values in `$variables['breadcrumb']` and run a `str_replace` to get rid of the active class.

Comment: Thank you. This idea worked. I wrote a for loop that removed the active class. Unfortunately google is still throwing an error for the Structured Data, but that is a separate issue. Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery .removeclass() on document load so that it removes 'active' from breadcrumb for each page.

More information here.

[jQuery remove class](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Ideally I would like to do it without having to add Javascript to the page, but I might have to end up doing that.